# Why is the status message for avahi-daemon.service permanently "starting up"?

Tags: systemd, avahi

```
$ systemctl status avahi-daemon
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-05-08 08:01:52 BST; 8h ago
 Main PID: 817 (avahi-daemon)
   Status: "avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up."
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
           ├─817 avahi-daemon: running [alan-laptop.local]
           └─852 avahi-daemon: chroot helper

$ rpm -q avahi
avahi-0.7-12.fc28.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code for avahi-daemon source code includes several more status messages, e.g.

> sd_notifyf(0, "STATUS=Server startup complete. Host name is %s. Local service cookie is %u.", avahi_server_get_host_name_fqdn(s), avahi_server_get_local_service_cookie(s));

However, by default avahi-daemon enters a secure chroot during startup. This means it can't access the systemd notification socket `/run/systemd/notify`. It has blocked itself from sending status messages to systemd. Oops.

```
# ls -l /proc/817/root
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 May  8 16:27 /proc/817/root -> /etc/avahi
# ls -l /proc/817/root/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1753 Jul 10  2017 avahi-daemon.conf
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr  6 16:48 etc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1121 Jul 10  2017 hosts
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr  6 16:48 services
```

Comment: avahi-daemon implements some workarounds to break outside of chroot.  See the `chroot.c` source file in avahi-daemon.  E.g. it already does something special for `/etc/resolv.conf` and its own D-Bus features.  Perhaps it can just be fixed.